# Can't access to object properties using angular

Tags: angularjs

I can't access my object properties in my app. It looks like it's a controller problem but I have started from scratch twice and isn't apparently that.

My HTML is the following:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>URL</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
        <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
        <td>{{movie.url}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And my controller is the following one:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name clientApp.controller:MoviesCtrl
 * @description
 * # MoviesCtrl
 * Controller of the clientApp
 */
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.movies = [
     {
         title: 'Star Wars',
         url: 'www.youtube.com'
     }
    ];
  });
```

Any ideas?

I expect to have:

[Exepected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxrd4.png)

And it just appear:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjYN6.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your actual question here?  you haven't described anything about what you expect or what you are actually seeing, or any errors you might be getting, and you haven't even provided a **full** example of your code;  there is no reference to the angular app or controller anywhere in this HTML.  please see how to create a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: You need to include your ng-app scope and controller scope for working of above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference the application and the controller into the view, and the right syntax to reference the module.

This a a little tricky, but you build a module with this syntax:

```
angular.module('MODULE_NAME', [ /* Insert optional module dependency here */ ]);
```

And you use the created module with this syntax:

```
angular.module('MODULE_NAME').controller()
```

It appears that the creation of the module returns the module itself, so you can also use the most condense syntax:

```
angular.module('MODULE_NAME', []).controller()
```

Which is a bit misleading because you don't see the distinction between the creation and the usage. And you have to be warn that executing twice this command: `angular.module('MODULE_NAME', [])` will lead to an (very common) error.

See this working example:

```js
// declare a module
var clientAppModule= angular.module('clientApp', []);

// configure the module.    
clientAppModule.controller('ClothesCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.clothes = [
     {
         name: 'T-shirt',
         description: 'Cool T-shirt'
     }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <table ng-app='clientApp'
           ng-controller='ClothesCtrl'>
    <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>URL</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cloth in clothes">
            <td>{{cloth.name}}</td>
            <td>{{cloth.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: what is different from the answer i posted?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing dependencies inection to the module, and you have not mentioned ng-controller anywhere in the view

```
angular.module('clientApp',[])
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BSK5h14rUmlPdJDu9KT2?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much @Cyril Gandon! I haven't defined the name of the controller in my view and I was missing that. Thanks!!

Comment: @RafaelHernandez can you markas answer if it had helped